# How to view JIRA issues in Confluence when the JIRA server can't "see" the Confluence server

Tags: networking, jira, confluence

Our network topology is configured such that our Confluence 6.15.2 server can have network access to our JIRA 7.13.2 server, but not vice versa.  This restriction is immutable, so answers must not include "reconfigure your network", "add a firewall exception", etc.

Is there any way to configure Confluence such that it can display JIRA issues?  Most of my research suggests the link between JIRA and Confluence must be bidirectional, but in our situation JIRA cannot "see" Confluence due to firewall/policy restrictions.  I'm wondering if there's a "one-way link" option such that Confluence can pull information from JIRA but not push information into JIRA.